# How to customize the foreign key names used in DataNucleus JDO inheritance hierarchies?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

The [JDO Inheritance](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jdo/orm/inheritance.html) guide for DataNucleus mentions that in `InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE` class relationships, a foreign key will be created between the superclass' and subclass' tables. Running the DataNucleus schema generator, I do see that such a foreign key is being generated. What I can't discover, though, is how the names for these foreign keys can be customized.

For example:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "login_identities")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
public abstract class AbstractLoginIdentity { ... }

@PersistenceCapable(table = "email_login_identities")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
public class EmailLoginIdentity extends AbstractLoginIdentity { ... }
```

Given those classes, DataNucleus will generate a foreign key like the following (for PostgreSQL):

```
-- Constraints for table "email_login_identities" for class(es) [com.trickle.api.accounts.EmailLoginIdentity]
ALTER TABLE "email_login_identities" ADD CONSTRAINT "email_login_identities_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("id") REFERENCES "login_identities" ("id") ;
```

I can't discover any way to alter the "`email_login_identities_FK1`" constraint's name. Adding a `@ForeignKey` annotation to the subclass just adds a new foreign key.

Can this be customized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foot of [this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jdo/orm/constraints.html#fk) shows how to define a foreign key for the join to superclass, using XML.

I don't see a way of doing that in annotations (since `@Inheritance` has no `@Join`, and `@Join` has no `@ForeignKey`) ... but then I would never want to hardcode ORM definitions **into a Java class**. I assume you could request such a facility in annotations via the Apache JDO people.

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer! I was able to specify the FK name via an additional `.orm` file for the class, which solved my problem. (I used to feel the same way as you about not specifying ORM metadata in annotations, but have since decided that it's better to have everything in one place, when I only need to support one RDBMS platform.)